# Custom post type single page not deregistering style and scripts

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, enqueue

I have a website where I have a custom post type with some single pages attached to it.

**Problem:** I can't deregister the scripts and styles on my custom post type single pages.

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
   if (is_page(array(20720, 38881))) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
     }
        elseif (is_home()) {     
        wp_deregister_script( 'theme-my-login-ajax' );
     }

     elseif (is_singular( 'name-of-my-custom-post-type' )) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'incom-js');
     }

        elseif (is_page(array(alfabet-page))) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'wp-favroite-posts' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'basic-comment-quicktags' );
     }
```

So you can see that I am using it like this:

```
 elseif (is_singular( 'name-of-my-custom-post-type' )) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'incom-js');
 }
```

Yet this does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** even when removing the others, it does not work at all:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {

     if (is_singular( 'my_custom_posttype_page_name' )) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'incom-js');
     }
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_styles', 100 );

function my_deregister_styles() {

    if (is_singular( 'my_custom_posttype_page_name' )) {
        wp_deregister_style( 'incom-style');
     }

}
```

Comment: I think your elseif is the problem - have you tried to use only IF's?

Comment: But I have multiple others and they are working. Should I separate this one just for this specific one? I have not tried that one yet...

Comment: Yes, I think separating them will do the job. I encountered issue with elseif before - for some reason the code checks first one and if its true or false it just skips the entire code to end and keeps going....

Comment: See updated question.... still not working :( I don't get what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Are there any errors in the PHP error log?

Comment: For PHP error logging, see https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/php-logging-basics/ You can print a message to the error log using `error_log('message here');` to see if any of your code is reached.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems wrong: `elseif (is_page(array(alfabet-page))) {`. Did you forget a `$` in front of `alfabet-page`? I think your code is printing errors to the log, and maybe stopping at that line.

Comment: No, I don't think that that is the problem. Tried doing that, but does not help. I used the codex btw: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/